# rails form_tag doesn't work anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Surprisingly i can't make this simple form_tag to send me the params.. for an hour.. It worked on my last project. I did a copy of it, used different Ruby version and now it doesn't work. Tried many things but it just don't work.

I have this block:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div id="light-pagination" class="pagination"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style='float:right'>
    <%= form_tag("/go_to_show_question", class: "form-inline", method: "get") do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag(:id, @question_group.id) %>
        <%= search_field_tag :question, '', size: 5, class: 'form-control' %> 
        <%= submit_tag r("tests.go_to_question"), class: 'btn btn-default' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div><br>
```

I am inputting a number and clicking on 'Go to question'. And it sends only:

```
{"controller"=>"question_groups", "action"=>"go_to_show_question", "locale"=>"en"}
```

Where is 'id' and 'question'? why they are not sent together?

I believe this is something stupid but i cant find what.. It worked before. I didnt change it i believe.

This is the generated HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div id="light-pagination" class="pagination"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style='float:right'>
    <form class="form-inline" action="/go_to_show_question" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
      <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="28" />
      <input type="search" name="question" id="question" value="" size="5" class="form-control" /> 
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Go to question" class="btn btn-default" />
    </form>          
  </div>
</div><br>
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  ... other routes ...

  scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.config.available_locales.join("|")}/ do

    ... other routes ...

    get 'go_to_show_question' => 'question_groups#go_to_show_question'

    ... other routes ...

  end
  get '*path', to: redirect("/#{(I18n.locale)}/%{path}"), constraints: lambda { |req| !req.path.starts_with? "/#{I18n.locale}/" }
  match '', to: redirect("/#{(I18n.locale)}"), via: [:get, :post, :put, :delete]
end
```

Controller:

```
class QuestionGroupsController < ApplicationController
  def go_to_show_question
    redirect_to show_question_group_path(:id => params[:id], :question => (params[:question].to_i - 1))
  end
end
```

This request reaches my controller. but without id, question params.

And this is the Log

```
Processing by QuestionGroupsController#go_to_show_question as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
{"controller"=>"question_groups", "action"=>"go_to_show_question", "locale"=>"en"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/en/show_question_group?question=-1
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Comment: show me your routes

Comment: its look like you declare routes in `locale` scop

Comment: `go_to_show_question/:id` try this routes

Comment: Yes. all my project must be in locale scope.

Comment: if i make `go_to_show_question/:id` then i have to remake my HTML form_tag. But it worked like that before. It must have send the id and question params, but it just doesnt send.

Comment: yes you are right it should work without route changes,can you please restart server

Comment: I did, still the same - params are not merged. I have also the same problem on production

Comment: it strange let me trace it

Comment: what you mean? How do i let you trace it?

Comment: can you change `:id` to some other name in hidden_filed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132575/discussion-between-uzaif-and-mansim).

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

```
<%= form_tag("/en/go_to_show_question", class: "form-inline", method: "get") do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag(:id, @question_group.id) %>
        <%= search_field_tag :question, '', size: 5, class: 'form-control' %> 
        <%= submit_tag r("tests.go_to_question"), class: 'btn btn-default' %>
    <% end %>
```

I just didnt add the locale in front of my URL of form. 
Even trough my route worked fine, but the :locale scope parsed the request and deleted my params.

It was like

```
Started GET "/go_to_show_question?utf8=%E2%9C%93&id=28&question=88&commit=Go+to+question" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-07 16:41:08 +0100
```

parsed into

```
Started GET "/en/go_to_show_question" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-07 16:41:08 +0100
Processing by QuestionGroupsController#go_to_show_question as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
```